# Unable to use port even if sudo is used to create a domain for glassfish in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, glassfish

I am trying to create a domain in glassfish. I have already done this in another server with ubuntu 12.04. Everything worked fine.

I was just trying to replicate the same setup in another server with ubuntu 12.04

1. Downloaded the glassfish 3.1.2 zip from oracle
2. Unzipped it to opt
3. ran sudo ./asadmin and ran the command to create domain on adminport 5050 and many other ports

i got the same error

You do not have the permission to use port 5050 for domain1. Try a different port number or login as a more privileged user.

The user i am using has sudo access. I am not able to get this started because of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when I get permission errors (even when using `sudo`) what I'll do is actually switch to the root user.

for instance:

```
$ sudo su
Password:[enter password]
#
```

The "#" shows you're operating as the root user and you can do more than you can with just `sudo` alone.